# How to send url to a html file

Tags: html, web-config

I'm trying to verify my domain for GoDaddy and I want to go the HTML route in doing so.  Here are my options:

https://www.godaddy.com/help/verify-domain-ownership-html-or-dns-7452

I want to just make a simple change in the web.config file so that when I hit http://coolexample.com/.well-known/pki-validation/godaddy.html it will hit the html file that I created with my unique ID.

I tried:

```
<location path="godaddy.html">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://localhost/showpass.ui" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

but of course that isn't quite right,I'm sure its simple but I can't quite get it

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply transfer the file to your server's root using an FTP client like [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client) or the one integrated with your hosting solution (GoDaddy in your case).